# Usage of go channels

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm looking for validation/better design for the below functionality using go channels -
Process X in main() has to run after a polling process. After starting process X, it needs to be checked every minute if it is running successfully. On a failure, the process needs to restarted after polling again (if required).

```
startX := make(chan bool)
startedX := make(chan bool)
startX <- true
    for {
        select {
        case <-startX:
            //Check if a worked needs to be started
            poll()
            // Start process
            X.Run()
            // Started X
            startedX <- true
        case <-startedX:
            // keep polling for errors
            rePoll()
            // cancel on error
            X.cancel()
            // return to startX (To see if the worker needs to be restarted or if another worker has already been started)
            startX <- true
        }
    }
```

This implementation works! But is there a better way of doing the above? Thanks much!

Comment: Why do you need channels here at all: why not just use a boolean value? And you probably don't even need that - an infinite loop that runs `rePoll` after you started would work identically: `for {
    poll()
    X.Run()
    rePoll()
    X.cancel()
}`

Comment: I think you probably want one go routine that is checking X and using a time.Ticker to poll every certain amount of time.